# Advantages of redirecting to a login page versus having a drop down menu login form with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I've noticed that a lot of big sites, namely gmail, require you to redirect to a specific login page where others will have a drop down menu to login. What are the advantages/disadvantages of both?

Thanks a lot

Comment: No obvious advantages. It is suggested that login form on every page makes it faster to login. Maybe. But internals are the same - some request goes to server, being processed, response returned. Matter of choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary advantage of having a logon mechanism integrated into the page is it provides the ability to logon and/or create a user account without losing the context of what the user is doing.

For example, on StackOverflow a user can enter a new question or answer without being logged on.  Upon clicking the "Submit" button, they are prompted if they want to create an account or use an existing account.  This can be done without losing the information by redirecting to another page.

Another example could be on a recipe website.  A user might find a recipe they like, and click on the "Add To Favorites" button.  If they're not already logged on, a popup box could allow them to create an account or logon with an existing account.  When done, the recipe would then be added to their favorites within their newly created account.  The alternative would be a logon link that goes to a different page, forcing the user to then find the recipe they were interested in again once they were logged on.  This severely disrupts user flow and could potentially cost a lot of users.

A separate logon page has the advantage of being easier to implement.  Pages that have "secure" information can simply redirect to the logon page, rather than having to worry about rendering UI without the context of a valid session.

Overall, it's a choice that has to be made depending on the context of your website, after a careful study of user habits, and tested on a realistic sampling of your user base.  I think this decision is definitely not arbitrary, nor should it be taken lightly.

Answer (score 1):

From a user-interface perspective, it depends on how much functionality you want to provide to users who are not logged in.  If, like gmail, the answer is 'none', you have nothing to show non-logged-in users except the login form.  If you're a store website, you don't want to require that someone log in just to browse, but you do want to make it easy to log in from anywhere - so you put a login mechanism on each page.

Also, if you have a dedicated login page you can use it for more than just the one app.  Google's authentication system is significantly wider than just gmail.